# AWK Arrays, Redirecting Output

Tags: awk

I am looping through an awk array to print output and then want to insert this output into another file following a particular regular expression. Any thoughts?

```
for(i=1; i<=n; i++){                    
        printf("TILE%d_STRIP%d_TRANSLATE0,%.1f,%.1f\n",tile_num,i,x_array[i],y_array[i]);
    }
```

Which produces:

```
TILE1_STRIP1_TRANSLATE0,4122.9,5400.0
TILE1_STRIP2_TRANSLATE0,4122.9,5535.0
TILE1_STRIP3_TRANSLATE0,4122.9,5670.0
TILE1_STRIP4_TRANSLATE0,4122.9,5805.0
TILE1_STRIP5_TRANSLATE0,4122.9,5940.0
```

I then want these lines inserted into another file between these two lines

```
Site,Single,Single
<EOSUBSITES>
```

Comment: Post some related data, work so far and expected output, please.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bash process substitution:

```
sed -i '/^Site,Single,Single$/ r'<(awk '...') another_file
```

The `<()` is seen by bash as a filename, and the contents of the parentheses will be executed to generate the contents of the "file".

I have the process substitution concatenated with the preceding single-quoted string (with no whitespace in between) to form the sed program to run.

Comment: Can I use bash variables within that process substitution?

Comment: yes you can. The parentheses put the work into a subshell, but your current variables are available to it.